# cannot install package libstdc++

Tags: apt, package-management

I am getting an error when trying to install package libstdc:

https://www.hastebin.com/ayixiyozoq.sql

using `apt -f install` does not work.

need to use hastebin because of a character limit on askubuntu

Answer (score 3):

[There is no `libstdc++` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libstdc%2B%2B). There are [`libstdc++6`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/libstdc++6) and [`libstdc++-6-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/libstdc++-6-dev) packages.